# Winding a custom transformer with coil former

Tags: transformer, coil, winding, core

For a project I'm building a DC/DC convertor for converting 600VDC to 5VDC. Through the use of the TI Webench I was able to create a design, but it requires a custom wound transformer. The transformer report (provided by the TI Webench) reads as follows:
[image: transo-report-1]
[image: transfor-report-2]

I've gathered the necessary components, designed the PCB and soldered everything, but now I'm stuck on how I need to wind the transformer.
As the transformer report states I've bought some transformer cores (B66305G0000X127), a transformer coil former (B66202B1108T001) and some transformer yokes to keep everything together (B66202A2010X000). I've also bought the correct wires to use for this transformer.

Below is a picture of the cores, former and yoke (respectively, from left to right). Also a picture of how to assemble these pieces (I think) is included.
[image: transfo-parts]
[image: transfo-assembly]

Now my question is how do I route the wires through to create the correct transformer? Just all the way around the yokes? Or do I just wind everything around the coil former, and then add the cores around them? I've tried Google'ing this many times without a result, so some explanation or some websites with information would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Wind it around the coil former, then insert the core.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! Excellent question! +1

Answer (score 1):

You wind it at your convenience and it makes no sense to try and do that with the core in place. In addition, you use the commonly available yellow polyester tape to properly and reliably insulate the primary from the secondary. Any doubts on the secondary wires exiting the former possibly crossing too close to the primary and you run some insulation sheath up the wires close to where they solder to the pins.

Should you in fact be using triple insulated wire for the secondary then you won’t need the sheath. If this is your first design I’d definitely advise you to google the construction details and if in doubt raise a new question about the construction.